# Prove A = (A\B) ∪ (A ∩ B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to demonstrate this formulae:

Prove $A = (A\setminus B) ∪ (A ∩ B)$

But it seems to me that it is false.

> $(A\setminus B) ∪ (A ∩ B)$
>
> - $X \in A\setminus B \implies  { x ∈ A  \text{ and } x ∉ B }$
>
> or
>
> - $X ∈ A ∩ B \implies { x ∈ A \text{ and } x ∈ B }$

---

> so:
>
> $x ∈ A ∩ B$
>
> so:
>   $A ≠ (A\setminus B) ∪ (A ∩ B)$

Did I solve the problem or I am just blind?

Comment: Think of $(A\backslash B)$ as $A \cap B^c$.

Comment: Matt: Forgive my elementary knowledge, but what does it mean B^c$ ?

Comment: You did not solve the problem. If you want to show two sets $S_1, S_2$ are equal, i.e. $S_1 = S_2$ then you show $S_1 \subset S_2$ and $S_2 \subset S_1$.

Comment: $B^c$ (read "B complement") means all elements that are not in B.

Comment: I suppose the question is how you got to $x \in A \cap B$ from what you wrote above that. How did you conclude that?

Comment: There are 2 theorems available  here, one from set theory, one from logic. For sets X and Y, X=Y means X is Y, but the theorem from set theory says  two sets are equal if each is a subset of the other. The theorem from logic says that if you have two statements S and T and you wish to show S or T is true, it's enough to show that if S is false then T is true. These 2 theorems make your problem easy. They are basic tools that should be in your toolbox. I remember a class stuck on showing two fancy topologies were equal, until someone said let's just show  each topology is a subset of the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show that two sets are equal, you show they have the same elements.

Suppose first $x\in A$. There are two cases: Either $x\in B$, or $x\notin B$. In the first case, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, so $x\in A\cap B$ (by definition of intersection). In the second case, $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, so $x\in A\setminus B$ (again, by definition).

This shows that if $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\in A\setminus B$, i.e., $x\in (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$.

Now we have to show, conversely, that if $x\in (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$, then $x\in A$. Note that $x\in(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$ means that either $x\in A\setminus B$ or $x\in A\cap B$. In the first case, $x\in A$ (and also, $x\notin B$). In the second case, $x\in A$ (and also, $x\in B$). In either case, $x\in A$, but this is what we needed.

In summary: We have shown both $A\subseteq (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$ and $(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\subseteq A$. But this means the two sets are equal.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thanks! I used unicode characters for the mathematical symbols, but I see that you all use something else. Where can I read the syntax?

Comment: @Nerian: Have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117, and then Chapter 3 of http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf

Answer (score 3):

To show set equality you show $\supset$, $\subset$ respectively.

$\subset$:

Let $x \in A$. Then $x$ either in $A \cap B$ or in $A \cap B^c = A - B$, so $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A - B)$.

$\supset$:

Let $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A - B)$. Then either $x$ in $ A \cap B$ or x in $A \cap B^c$. But in both cases $x \in A$, therefore $x \in A$.

Answer (score 2):

$\rm\ A\backslash B\  =\ A\cap\overline B\ \ \:$ so $\rm\ \: (A\backslash B)\cup (A\cap B)\ =\ (A\cap\overline B)\cup(A\cap B)\ =\ A\cap(\overline B\cup B)\ =\ A$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in A$. Then $x \in A \backslash B$ or $x \in A \cap B$. Likewise, if $x \in A \backslash B$ or $x \in A \cap B$ then $x \in A$.

Answer (score 1):

Working inside a universe $X$: 
$$A = A \cap X = A \cap (B \cup (X \setminus B)) = ( A \cap B ) \cup ( A \cap (X \setminus B)) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \setminus B)$$

Comment: That's precisely the *reverse* of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using your initial arguments:

> $(A\setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$
>
> - $X \in A\setminus B \implies  { x \in A  \text{ and } x\not\in  B }$
>
> or
>
> - $X \in A \cap B \implies { x \in A \text{ and } x \in B }$

So what we have is $x\in A\setminus B$ non-exclusive OR $x\in  A \cap B$.

So  $ { x \in A  \text{ and } x\not\in  B } \lor { x \in A \text{ and } x \in B }$.

In Boolean logic this becomes $A \land (B\lor ¬B)=A$.

Answer (score 0):

For all, each, any, and every $x$ we have $$(x\in A)\iff ((x\in A\land x\in B)\lor (x\in A\land x\not \in B))\iff$$ $$\iff (x\in A\cap B)\lor (x\in A \backslash B).$$